# Python Pandas dataframe user search function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, search

I have a Pandas CSV file and I would like to know how to create a Python user search function to find a row. Below is a sample of the CSV -
[image]

I would like to create a function whereby it ask the user for the ICAO code, which is one of the columns, then it returns the whole row of information. For example if someone typed EHAM it would return all the information in that row (Position, ICAO, Airport, Country, Total Movements, Position Change in the last 24hrs)
As a bonus but I am not sure it is possible, I would also love to show the 2 rows above and 2 rows below the requested search when displaying the results. So for example it would show not only EHAM, but also EDDF, EGKK (2 rows above) and also KBOS and KATL (2 rows below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code for the exact match. Suppose your CSV file is stored in a data frame called `df`

```py
icao = input("Enter the ICAO code: ")
print(df[df["ICAO"] == icao]])
```

Moreover, if you believe that the input value has at least one instance in the data frame, and indices are in an incremental order, you can try the following one:

```py
icao = input("Enter the ICAO code: ")
requested = df[df["ICAO"] == icao]]
print(df.iloc[requested.index[0] - 2 : requested.index[0] + 3, :])
```

Furthermore, you have to decide what do you want to do for the instances in the first two or last two rows.